# Some questions to canonical correlations between principle components and asset pricing factors using R

Tags: factor-models, asset-pricing, pca

I have done a asympotical principle component analysis (APCA), using `eigen()` in R, of the covariance matrix of a global dataset of excess returns.
I took the resulting eigenvectors (E) of the top principle components as a set and compared them with another set containing 5 asset pricing factors (F) using the function `cancor(F,E)`, ending in 5 canonical pairs with canonical correlations

```
    $cor
[1] 0.9538597 0.8230864 0.8126250 0.8076996 0.7953763
```

- Now the question arises for me, how exactly I have to understand this output and how I can interpret these numbers?
- Furthermore, I wonder what is generally meant by "Eigenvector weights for the principle components"? Are these $\sqrt{Eigenvalues}$ ?

Thank you in advance!